# Facing issue with handwriting recognition

Tags: java, android

In my app with webview, which is having fields for example like first-name,last-name,phone & email,when trying to enter data through handwriting recognition am facing issues,suddenly at some field it stops working,though am writing on panel it does not take data and also refuses to clear the field,any suggestions or ideas please help